# вложения в циклах foreach при парсинге

Tags: php, foreach

Нужна помощь есть html дерево где с помощью DomCrawler парсим нужные нам значения(имя товара и цена) сложность в том как из двух масивов сделать один(ключ значение) в разных цыклах форич
Пример:
...php

```
foreach ($div_elements as $a => $names) {  

     // this code gets goods names from thml_DOM
    $crawler = new Crawler($names);
    foreach ($crawler->filter('h6[class="name"]') as $i => $node_h6) {

        $tds[] = $node_h6->nodeValue;
        }
         $array_name[] = $tds;
       // this code gets goods price from thml_DOM
         foreach ($crawler->filter('span[class="price-new"]') as $i => $node_span) {

            $tds1[] = $node_span->nodeValue;
        }
        $price[] = $tds1;
        var_dump($array_name);
        echo "<hr>";
        var_dump($price);

}
```

...php
вывод

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(36) "LED панель (315x310 мм) 120W"
    [1]=>
    string(49) "LED фитопанель (Grow Light GP UFO) 140W"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "VIPARSPECTRA 600W"
    [3]=>
    string(25) "Комплект ДНаТ"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "4140грн."
    [1]=>
    string(11) "8400грн."
    [2]=>
    string(12) "16065грн."
    [3]=>
    string(10) "600грн."
  }
```

Comment: а откуда у вас берется массив для внешнего цикла?

Comment: $array_name[$tds]=$tds1;

Comment: teran4 массив получаю из файла, который заполняю содержимым из сайта)

Comment: Bloom так пробовал но получаю Warning:  Illegal offset type in, в любом месте цыкла

Comment: первый фильтр для получения массива $div_elements = $crawler->filterXPath('//body');